# python variable length values in dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d1 = {2: 'Joe', 5: 'Bob',  7: 'Doug', 9 : 'Bob', 10 : 'Doug', 12 : 'Joe', 15 : 'Dave'}
```

I want to use it to fill a different dictionary like this:

```
 def MakeDict():
     d, myList = {}, []
     for num in range(np.max(d1.keys())+1):
         value = d1.get(num)
         if value != None and value not in myList:
             myList.append(value)
         d[num] = myList
     return d
```

I would like the function to return this:
0:[],1:[], 2:['Joe'], 3:['Joe'], 4:['Joe'], 5:['Joe','Bob'], 6: ['Joe':'Bob'], 7:['Joe','Bob','Doug'], etc.

instead it is returning this:
0: ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Doug'], 1: ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Doug'], 2: ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Doug'], 3: ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Doug'] ...

I assume it is not working the way I would like it to because the len of the list is changing.  Is there a way of getting around that?

Comment: Do you mind explaining `3:['7'], 4:['7'], 5:['7','1'], 6: ['7':'1'], 7:['7','1', '25']`?

Comment: What is the logic behaind this? Why you have .e.g, `5:['7','1']` in your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that

```
mylst = []
d1[1] = mylst         # this is a reference, not a copy!
mylst.append('Joe')   # modify the object...
d1[1]                 # => ['Joe'] !
```

Instead, you want to

```
mylst = []
d1[1] = mylst[:]      # make a copy
mylst.append('Joe')
d1[1]                 # => []     # what you expected
```

---

```
d1 = {2: '7', 5: '1',  7: '25', 9 : '1', 10 : '25', 12 : '1', 15 : '55'}

d2, lst, seen = {}, [], set([None])
for i in range(max(d1) + 1):
    val = d1.get(i)
    if val not in seen:
        seen.add(val)
        lst.append(val)
    d2[i] = lst[:]
```

which gives

```
{0: [],
 1: [],
 2: ['7'],
 3: ['7'],
 4: ['7'],
 5: ['7', '1'],
 6: ['7', '1'],
 7: ['7', '1', '25'],
 8: ['7', '1', '25'],
 9: ['7', '1', '25'],
 10: ['7', '1', '25'],
 11: ['7', '1', '25'],
 12: ['7', '1', '25'],
 13: ['7', '1', '25'],
 14: ['7', '1', '25'],
 15: ['7', '1', '25', '55']}
```

Comment: i guess i did not make it clear in the question but I dont want any duplicate values

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = {2: '7', 5: '1',  7: '25', 9 : '1', 10 : '25', 12 : '1', 15 : '55'}
d2 = {}
prev = []
for i in range(max(d1.keys())+1):
    if i in d1:
        d2.setdefault(i, [x for x in prev]).append(d1[i])
    else:
        d2[i] = prev
    prev = d2[i]
print(d2)
```